# How to debug sluggish process performance

Tags: linux, performance

I have a test application which writes a string to a file 10000 times. I run this on two servers and I get totally different results.

```
[SYSTEM 1]

$ time ./test_depth 

real    0m0.152s
user    0m0.070s
sys     0m0.082s

    $ strace -cT ./test_depth 
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 57.38    0.000420           0     10000           write
 30.19    0.000221           0      9924           fadvise64
 12.43    0.000091           0     10000           gettid
  0.00    0.000000           0        11           read
  0.00    0.000000           0        66        54 open
  0.00    0.000000           0        11           close
  0.00    0.000000           0         7         6 stat
  0.00    0.000000           0        13           fstat
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           lseek
  0.00    0.000000           0        32           mmap
  0.00    0.000000           0        15           mprotect
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           munmap
  0.00    0.000000           0         3           brk
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           rt_sigaction
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           rt_sigprocmask
  0.00    0.000000           0         1         1 access
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           execve
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           uname
  0.00    0.000000           0         3           fcntl
  0.00    0.000000           0         1         1 unlink
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           symlink
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           getrlimit
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           arch_prctl
  0.00    0.000000           0         3         1 futex
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           set_tid_address
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           set_robust_list
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.000732                 30105        63 total

[SYSTEM 2]

$ time ./test_depth 

real    1m0.252s
user    0m0.163s
sys     0m0.307s

$ strace -cT ./test_depth 
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 98.29    0.147977          15     10000           write
  1.56    0.002355           0      9925           fadvise64
  0.14    0.000217           0     10000           gettid
  0.00    0.000006           1        11           close
  0.00    0.000000           0        11           read
  0.00    0.000000           0        57        45 open
  0.00    0.000000           0         3         3 stat
  0.00    0.000000           0        13           fstat
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           lseek
  0.00    0.000000           0        32           mmap
  0.00    0.000000           0        15           mprotect
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           munmap
  0.00    0.000000           0         3           brk
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           rt_sigaction
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           rt_sigprocmask
  0.00    0.000000           0         1         1 access
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           execve
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           uname
  0.00    0.000000           0         3           fcntl
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           unlink
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           symlink
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           getrlimit
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           arch_prctl
  0.00    0.000000           0         3         1 futex
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           set_tid_address
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           set_robust_list
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.150555                 30093        50 total
```

The process runs for about one minute on the second system. And looking at the strace, it spends 15 micro seconds on each `write` call. How do I continue diagnosing the problem from here? It just looks like the disc write is taking longer on the second system. How do I make sure if it is really that? And, what else should I be looking at?

The mounts being used in the two cases:

```
1) - /dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw)
2) - /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_home on /home type ext4 (rw)
```

By the way, The logs are being written using `glog` lib. If simple `printf` is used, this problem does not appear. So it seems like a problem with the library. :(

```
[root@localhost src]# hdparm -I /dev/sda

/dev/sda:
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0d 00 00 00 00 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

ATA device, with non-removable media
Standards:
    Likely used: 1
Configuration:
    Logical     max current
    cylinders   0   0
    heads       0   0
    sectors/track   0   0
    --
    Logical/Physical Sector size:           512 bytes
    device size with M = 1024*1024:           0 MBytes
    device size with M = 1000*1000:           0 MBytes 
    cache/buffer size  = unknown
Capabilities:
    IORDY not likely
    Cannot perform double-word IO
    R/W multiple sector transfer: not supported
    DMA: not supported
    PIO: pio0 
[root@localhost src]# df -k
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root
                      51606140   6267948  42716752  13% /
tmpfs                  8141564      1016   8140548   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda3               495844     37728    432516   9% /boot
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_home
                     1090839440   1022652 1034405284   1% /home


[root@localhost src]# ./lshw -class disk
  *-disk                  
       description: SCSI Disk
       product: PERC H310
       vendor: DELL
       physical id: 2.0.0
       bus info: scsi@0:2.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sda
       version: 2.12
       serial: 00677e1515fc98ef19000d93f7a0a38c
       size: 1117GiB (1199GB)
       capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
       configuration: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512 signature=31c27a66
```

OSs:

```
[SYSTEM 1]
Linux snapoffice 2.6.32-71.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri May 20 03:51:51 BST 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

[SYSTEM 2]
Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jun 22 12:19:21 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: I'd start by looking at the mount options (`mount`). Is the second one mounted `sync`?

Comment: Hi Halfgaar, how do I check this?

Comment: Looks like the mounts for the two systems are : (1) - `/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw)`, (2) - `/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_home on /home type ext4 (rw)`

Comment: Can you edit your posts with what hardware you're using? Do you perhaps have a RAID controller on which write cache is disabled?

Comment: @Halfgaar: Thanks for the pointers. The culprit was glog flushing on each write. After configuring glog not to flush on each write the process is performing as the first. However, in the first system itself, glog is configured to flush on each write but it doesnt cause a problem. Wonder why?

Comment: Hard to say. Are both OS's the same? I do know that ext4 has something called delayed allocation (which is nasty). Perhaps one server deals with that differently than the other.

Comment: @Halfgaar: Added OS's please check.

Comment: I cannot use flush timer on glog because that would mean the contents of log will not be up to date